# Rcharts hplot (Highcharts) colors attribute not working

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I have the following code:

```
library(rCharts)
C <- 1000
R <- 0.02
t <- 10

PV <- sapply(c(1:t), function(x) C*(1+R)^(-1*x))
TotPV <- sum(PV)
PVs <- data.frame(Time = c(1:t),PV)

h1 <- hPlot(x = 'Time', y = 'PV', data = PVs, type = 'line')

h1$tooltip(formatter = "#! function(){return('<b>t: </b>' + this.x + '<br/>' + '<b>PV: </b>' + this.y);} !#")
h1$colors(list('red'))

# h1$title(text = '')
# h1$xAxis(title = list(text = ''))
# h1$yAxis(title = list(text = 'PV'))
# h1$params$width <-200
# h1$params$height <- 200

h1
```

The problem is that the line color is not red but transparent. If I comment out the colors attribute, the line color changes to default (light blue). Anyone an idea?

Comment: The strange thing is that if I add a duplicate series to the plot and color both lines red it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
h1$colors(list('red'))
```

You can try adding:

```
h1$plotOptions(series = list(color = 'red'))
```